# How do I slim down SBERT's sentencer-transformer library?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface, large-language-model, sentence-transformers

SBERT's (https://www.sbert.net/) `sentence-transformer` library (https://pypi.org/project/sentence-transformers/) is the most popular library for producing vector embeddings of text chunks in the Python open source LLM ecosystem. It has a simple API but is a **MASSIVELY large** dependency. Where does all its bloat come from?

Below is a screenshot of building a base Docker container image with this tool which took over `11 mins` to build with a final image size of `7.5 GB`:

[image: base docker image]

For reference, here is my `Dockerfile.base`:

```
FROM python:3.11.2-slim-bullseye
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install sentence-transformers
```

I anticipated that this is because it is installed with some models already pre-packaged, but when I tried their popular getting started snippet

```py
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
model = SentenceTransformer('all-MiniLM-L6-v2')
embeddings = model.encode("vectorize this text")
```

it downloaded another few hundred MBs of more files to my filesystem. So I'd like to find a way of slimming this down to just the packages I need. I believe the size of this library is largely due to the underlying `torch` dependencies (`6.9 GB`), which in turn takes up a lot disk space due to its underlying `nvidia-*` dependencies (to where are these installed btw?)

Let's suppose I already have a model I've downloaded to my file system (i.e. `path/to/all-MiniLM-L6-v2` repo from HuggingFace), and all I want to do is run the code above on just a CPU. How can I install only the things I need without the bloat?

Now let's suppose I've picked a GPU to run this on. What are the next set of marginal dependencies I need to get this code to run without the bloat?

Comment: One thing you can do to make the pip install smaller is to use `pip install --no-cache-dir sentence-transformers`. Pip caching is never useful for Docker builds, and it makes the image bigger.

Comment: @NickODell TIL this flag! Cool, so using `--no-cache-dir` brought my image size down to `5.01 GB`. Going a step further, are there other layers of bloat I can trim?

Comment: @NickODell (missed the 5 min window to edit comment above) To clarify, using `--no-cache-dir` brought my SBERT image size down to `5.01 GB` and my torch image size down to `4.58 GB`.

Comment: @nmurthy can you please post the dockerfile if you have solved this issue?

Answer (score 12):

> it downloaded another few hundred MBs of more files to my filesystem. So I'd like to find a way of slimming this down to just the packages I need. I believe the size of this library is largely due to the underlying torch dependencies (6.9 GB), which in turn takes up a lot disk space due to its underlying nvidia-* dependencies (to where are these installed btw?)

I like to use the [docker dive tool](https://github.com/wagoodman/dive) to answer that kind of question. Besides the cache dir, it seems like most of the image's space is used by `/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages`. In particular, a lot of space seems to be being used by `/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/nvidia` and `/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch`.

> Let's suppose I already have a model I've downloaded to my file system (i.e. path/to/all-MiniLM-L6-v2 repo from HuggingFace), and all I want to do is run the code above on just a CPU. How can I install only the things I need without the bloat?

There are two suggestions I would make.

1. The first is `--no-cache-dir`. Currently it is storing 2.4 GB of cached packages inside `/root/.cache`. You can prevent that by rewriting this Dockerfile to:

   ```
   FROM python:3.11.2-slim-bullseye
   RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install --no-cache-dir sentence-transformers
   ```
2. The second suggestion I would give is using the CPU only version of torch. A lot of the dependencies are just for running the model on an Nvidia GPU.

   The following Dockerfile installs just the CPU only dependencies.

   ```
   FROM python:3.11.2-slim-bullseye
   RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip
   RUN pip install --no-cache-dir torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu
   RUN pip install --no-cache-dir sentence-transformers
   ```

   This results in an image size of 1.39GB.

> Now let's suppose I've picked a GPU to run this on. What the next set of marginal dependencies I need to get this code to run without the bloat?

I don't know enough about CUDA to know what parts of it you could remove without breaking it, sorry.

Comment: Nice, I reproduced these Docker commands and also achieved the same image size which built in under 4 mins. Thanks for the `--index-url` suggestion! I'm going to have do some research about Nvidia and CUDA to figure out that last bit (also thanks for the `dive` tip, another tool I learned today!)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this answer should be accepted (noting we could probably trim it down further using multi stage build etc, but going from ~8Gb to 2Gb is already great!).